# How include androidplot module in project

Tags: android, graph

I am trying to implement the andoridplot library in my app. I have download sample code from the github.sample is working fine. But if I am trying to import androidplot-core as a module in my project, I get this error:

> Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.

Please suggest the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add the following to your buildscript section of your gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}
```

Just a note: The preferred way to include Androidplot is as a normal compile dependency in gradle, not as a module.